# How to go about WLAN communication on two Android Phones

Tags: android, synchronization, communication, p2p, wifi

Is there a way to go about getting 2 android phones to communicate to each other locally without going through a central server? Sort of like being on WLAN? I need these 2 phones to be able to sync themselves to each other when they are nearby and running the same app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android, peer-to-peer, open source solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359931/android-peer-to-peer-open-source-solution)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe through bluetooth perhaps? Just a suggestion, I'm not sure how to go about this, but an idea might be to have each app broadcast through a certain port on LAN whilst searching for the other's broadcast through the same port. Once the other device has been identified, then transfer the data.

Answer (score 0):

The only ways to do that with WLAN environment (and not included a AP i.e infrastructure mode)

1. Ad-Hoc mode (Google will help you more on this)
2. Wi-Fi direct - that is the future of peer-to-peer with WLAN. (Again am sure Google will be more than happy to help you!)